# Why does Nuxt build generate a static site?

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt app which utilizes a custom API inside serverMiddleware and I want it to render on client side like a traditional Vue app. In my Nuxt config I have

```json
{
  ssr: false,
  target: "server"
}
```

Now when I run `nuxt build` I would expect it to build a server application, however it seems to generate a static site instead as I get this output:

```
> nuxt build

i Production build
i Bundling only for client side
i Target: static
i Using components loader to optimize imports
i Discovered Components: .nuxt/components/readme.md
√ Builder initialized
√ Nuxt files generated

√ Client
  Compiled successfully in 10.94s


Hash: 7d26eccbb5ace107e9e2
Version: webpack 4.46.0
Time: 10943ms
Built at: 14.12.2021 02:42:25
                                            Asset       Size                  Chunks                         Chunk Names
                                            /* ...a whole lot of static assets... */
 + 1 hidden asset
Entrypoint app = dcba269.js 1974de7.js 2a4b4e1.js 40505fc.js
i Generating output directory: dist/
i Generating pages
√ Generated route "/search"
√ Generated route "/"
√ Client-side fallback created: 200.html


   ╭──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                                                                      │
   │   ⚠ Nuxt Warning                                                                    │
   │                                                                                      │
   │   The command 'nuxt build' finished but did not exit after 5s                        │
   │   This is most likely not caused by a bug in Nuxt                                    │
   │   Make sure to cleanup all timers and listeners you or your plugins/modules start.   │
   │   Nuxt will now force exit                                                           │
   │                                                                                      │
   │   DeprecationWarning: Starting with Nuxt version 3 this will be a fatal error        │
   │                                                                                      │
   ╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please share your whole `nuxt.config.js` and `package.json`? Or maybe you do even have a github repo?

Comment: @kissu yes I created a repo here: https://github.com/DaDoBaag/nuxt-build-static

Comment: Oh yeah, I know why it fallbacks to `static`. Why are you trying to have `target: 'server'` here if you don't want SSR? It's like ordering a pizza, asking "could you make me a chorizo pizza, but without the chorizo?" If you don't use any SSR capabilities (`ssr: false`), there is no point into generating a project with a Node.js server. You could probably force it. Meanwhile, do you plan on hosting it on a VPS and pay for it, rather than hosting it on Vercel/Netlify/alike for free?

Comment: @kissu I have serverMiddleware in my real project so I need target server for that to work and deploy to Heroku. The Nuxt docs also explicitly say that my setup should work: "You can still run Nuxt with server hosting with ssr: false but Nuxt will not fully render the HTML for each page - leaving that task to the browser. You might choose this option if you need serverMiddleware but do not want fully server-side rendered HTML." (https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/deployment-targets#server-hosting)

Comment: Oh yeah indeed, sorry! For that, you may try `npm run build --force-build`.

Comment: @kissu --force-build doesn't change anything unfortunately. It's still generating a static site.

Comment: Totally works on my side: https://i.imgur.com/HMbyxwB.png

Comment: @kissu it says you are bundling for **server and client side** which means you didn't set `ssr: false`. I want it to bundle for **client side only**.

Comment: I actually git clone'd your project for this one. A question about skipping the client build was asked [on Discord](https://discord.com/channels/473401852243869706/484009060342169605/652139553448263700) but with no answer so far. Even tho, even if it's building the `server` bundle, it doesn't mean that it will actually use it. Also, I think that it's either written like that in the Nuxt project or that `serverMiddleware` is bundled inside of the server bundle (which should be logic). Either way, since you're trying to hack something here, IMO this solution is fine enough for your use-case.

Comment: @kissu I also just did a fresh git clone of my repo and when I run `npm run build --force-build` I get the following output: https://imgur.com/a/FjUpqvt - Why is mine different from yours?

Comment: Nvm haha, I am actually a bit off since I've edited `ssr: true` here. Sorry, didn't noticed until I made a git status. I guess I don't know so, sorry on this one!

Comment: @kissu alright thank you very much for trying to help, I will post an answer here if I can figure it out.